# jQuery Live Doesn't Update Attributes Dom

Tags: jquery, title, attr, livequery

I have a problem about getting title attribute..

```
$('.copy_button').livequery(function(event){
    $(this).zclip({
        path:'http://togl.me/tema/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: $(this).attr("title")
    });
});
```

The `livequery` function is working but I can't get `attr('title')` to work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using any plugins? `livequery` is not a standard jQuery method.

Comment: Yes all of them has a title and I'm using livequery also tried jquery.live.. You can check the problem here http://togl.me.. The problem is really different.. You will understand

Comment: Try this: enter http://togl.me. Shorten 1 link. Copy doesn't work... Then refresh the page.. When page loaded I get your last shortened links via Ajax.. But those works fine..

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the scope of `$(this)` can change based on where you're at in your method. As you start getting deeper, `$(this)` can refer to what's currently in scope, instead of what was evented in the first place.

Try doing this and tell me if it works:

```
$('.copy_button').livequery(function(event){
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).zclip({
        path:'http://togl.me/tema/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: title
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
$('.copy_button').livequery(function(event){
    $(this).zclip({
        path:'http://togl.me/tema/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: this.attr("title")
    });
});
```